# How to add record well using ASP.NET MVC and KnockoutJS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click:function(){show('add');}">Add</button>
```

My purpose is adding my input record values into the backend with an automatically Id number. But after I click button Add, show me Internal Server Error. The record was saved into the database sometimes. but the Id was 0. I have already set the Id property is Nullable. Below are my Add function and object. May I get some ideas from you smart guys? Thank you very much.

```
    self.addCustomer = function () {
    debugger;
    var cus = { Name : self.cusName(), Address: self.cusAddress()}
    var url = "/Customer/AddCustomer";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: cus,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Insert Successful!");
            GetCustomers();
            $('#AddCustomer').modal('hide');
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.statusText);
        }
    });
};
self.customers = ko.observableArray([]);
GetCustomers();
function GetCustomers() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Customer/GetCustomer",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            self.customers(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.statusText);
        }
    });
}
self.getSelected = function (cus) {
    self.cusId(cus.Id),
    self.cusName(cus.Name),
    self.cusAddress(cus.Address)
};
```

The back end post action.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddCustomer(CustomerModel customer)
    {
        var cus = new Customer
        {
            //Id = customer.Id,
            Name = customer.Name,
            Address = customer.Address
        };
        customerContext.Customers.Add(cus);
        customerContext.SaveChanges();
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deserialized, all parameters for a controller end-point are given a "default" value if one is not specified in the data. The default value for an integer in C# is 0. So all the integer properties of your CustomerModel will be 0 unless they are specifically told not to be.

I'm assuming `CustomerModel.ID` is an int since you didn't include that code. If that's correct try making it a `nullable<int>` instead. That way when a value is not specified the default given to it will be `null`.

The same issue applies to the `Customer` entity model as well. If that ID property isn't a nullable value it will be given a 0 default unless EntityFramework knows it's an auto-increment (identity) field.

Comment: Thanks, man. I change the Id property as a nullable int. But now both add and edit click event always show an "Internal Server error" dialog. I put the method Application_EndRequest in Global.aspx.cs, but still not working. :(

Comment: Otherwise, it works for a while, the Name and Address data saved into the database, but the Id still is 0. The internal server error is the next bug.